# Swiss Airlines long layover (10+ hours) in Zurich Airport - Eligible for hotel accommodation?

Tags: transit, hotels, zurich, swiss, zrh

I'm traveling with my family (with kids), from Frankfurt to US on Swiss Airlines. The trip will have long layover in Zurich Airport for more than 10 hours!

Are we eligible for hotel room accommodation or even access to rest area of the transit hotel during the transit time?

Comment: I would try to call Swiss Airlines and ask for another connection from Frankfurt to Zurich. They fly about 20 times a day, and there should be better connections available easily. With a family, you have good chances that they accommodate that for free. And even if you have to up-pay, it might be a good solution for you.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the long layover is due to a flight delay or cancellation, no, you are not entitled to anything more than any other passenger in your fare class. You agreed to it when you booked your flights, and everything else is your responsibility.

Comment: It's possible that Swiss have some scheme or fare class where there is such a thing available, no?

Comment: -1 for the condescending tone and general failure to address the question. Some airlines do offer perks like that, it's a legitimate question.

Comment: @Relaxed Some airlines do. If you find that Swiss does, please provide a link to that effect. My answer applies to the vast majority of airlines, including Swiss as far as I can tell.

Comment: My answer is correct for the vast majority of airlines, including Swiss as far as I can tell.

Comment: @fkraiem I certainly did not imply that Swiss does or does not offer hotel rooms… I would answer myself if I knew that for a fact. But you did not clearly answer the question yourself, you just wrote in a condescending tone that the OP is not “entitled” (a word that is nowhere to be found in the question) to anything else than what the airlines generally offers to passenger in his or her fare class. What this particular airline offers is precisely what the question is about and even if you did *know* that (as opposed to be merely guessing), there is no reason to be smug about it.

Comment: @Relaxed "Entitled" is a term of the art here, not an insult. Purchasing a flight ticket entitles the passenger to a bunch of goods and services, in this case not including a hotel room.

Comment: @jpatokal I don't think so, the last sentence and subsequent discussion makes it clear that fkraiem meant something else, i.e. that the OP is not entitled *by law* to anything out or the ordinary, which is true but wasn't the question and does nothing to clarify whether some fares do entitle Swiss passengers to a hotel stay during a layover or not. I stand by my assessment that this answer as written is both unnecessarily hostile and thoroughly uninformative.

Comment: @Relaxed You're reading way too much into this.  The answer is informative and correct: I'm also not aware of *any* carriers in Europe that still provide STPC (Stopover Paid by Carrier), unless you count Turkish, and even then only when there's >10 hrs between best available connections (not the case here).

Comment: @jpatokal I think you are the one who is reading too much into the answer, which makes it look better than it really is. “anything more than any other passenger in your fare class” leaves the question (namely what the OP is or is not in fact entitled to) entirely unanswered. It also reads as if fkraiem knew nothing about Swiss in particular (cf. “as far as I can tell”) and just assumed this was obvious as he did not initially bother to mention it or “most airlines” explicitly.

Comment: Incidentally, that statement would be equally true about Turkish airlines or any airline that would in fact offer complimentary lounge access or anything else you could dream of… A better answer would just state *explicitly* that Swiss does not offer anything (or at least something along the lines of what you just wrote) and leave the last sentence out (it adds nothing but condescension and is completely uncalled for given the tone of the question).

Answer (score 0):

Usually certain type business class tickets or frequent flyers have this kind of complimentary services. Anyway in the last decade free night during the stop over etc are not included .